# Java Web Service SOAP com objetos

Tags: java, web-service, soap, objetos, heroku

Olá, estou aprendendo a usar web-services e parei com um problema, talvez seja algo bobo, mas não achei solução, estou hospedando minha aplicação no Heroku e deixarei aqui as informações relevantes, porém antes devo explicar o que eu gostaria de fazer:

Fiz alguns testes simples de calculadoras e deu certo, porém quando tentei avançar um pouco nos exemplos, algo deu muito errado, minha intenção é que eu possa trabalhar com objetos, com isso eu poderei trabalhar com o banco de dados junto, mas não estou conseguindo, uma ultima tentativa foi este [tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/9123/jax-ws-tutorial/amp#advantages-of-web-services) onde basicamente fiz uma copia do mesmo sem alterações, pois se o exemplo funciona então eu poderia ver onde estava o meu erro.

Deixo agora o meu código e o erro que segue usando este mesmo exemplo:

No servidor:

Person.java

```
package ws.basico.ws_basico.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Person implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5577579081118070434L;

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private int id;

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public int getAge() { return age; }
    public void setAge(int age) { this.age = age; }

    public int getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }

    @Override
    public String toString(){ return "id: "+id+", nome: "+name+", idade: "+age; }
}
```

PersonService.java

```
package ws.basico.ws_basico.interfaces;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import ws.basico.ws_basico.model.Person;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
public interface PersonService {

    @WebMethod public boolean  addPerson(Person p);
    @WebMethod public boolean  deletePerson(int id);
    @WebMethod public Person   getPerson(int id);
    @WebMethod public Person[] getAllPersons();
}
```

PersonServiceImpl.java

```
package ws.basico.ws_basico.controller.services;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import ws.basico.ws_basico.interfaces.PersonService;
import ws.basico.ws_basico.model.Person;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "ws.basico.ws_basico.interfaces.PersonService", serviceName = "Person")  
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {

    private static Map<Integer,Person> persons = new HashMap<Integer,Person>();

    @Override
    public boolean addPerson(Person p) {
        if(persons.get(p.getId()) != null) { return false; }

        persons.put(p.getId(), p);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deletePerson(int id) {
        if(persons.get(id) == null)  { return false; }

        persons.remove(id);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Person getPerson(int id) { return persons.get(id); }

    @Override
    public Person[] getAllPersons() {
        Set<Integer> ids = persons.keySet();
        Person[] p = new Person[ids.size()];
        int i=0;

        for(Integer id : ids){
            p[i] = persons.get(id);
            i++;
        }

        return p;
    }
}
```

Loader.java

```
package ws.basico.ws_basico;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;
import ws.basico.ws_basico.controller.services.PersonServiceImpl;

public class Loader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String port    = System.getenv("PORT");
        String host    = "http://0.0.0.0:";
        String service = "/person";

        String url = host + port + service;

        SorteiaMensagem sm    = new SorteiaMensagem();

        Endpoint.publish(url, new PersonServiceImpl());

    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ws.basico</groupId>
    <artifactId>ws_basico</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>


 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>ws.basico.ws_basico.Loader</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build> 
</project>
```

Aqui tem o [WSDL](https://ws-basico.herokuapp.com/person?wsdl) gerado por este código.
Estou gerando e passando a aplicação para o heroku usando o Maven com os seguintes comandos:

```
mvn package
git add.
git commit -m "texto aqui"
git push heroku master
```

Creio não haver nada de diferente nos comandos git e nem na compilação do Maven, pois o sistema esta rodando no servidor, como pode ser visto no link acima.

Porém ao rodar um client é que encontra-se o erro.

Código do client:

PersonService.java

```
package ws_basico_consumidor.interfaces;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import ws_basico_consumidor.model.Person;

@WebService(name = "Person", targetNamespace = "http://ws_basico.basico.ws/")
public interface PersonService {

    public boolean  addPerson(Person p);
    public boolean  deletePerson(int id);
    public Person   getPerson(int id);
    public Person[] getAllPersons();
}
```

Ws_basico_consumidor.java

```
package ws_basico_consumidor;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import ws_basico_consumidor.model.Person;
import ws_basico_consumidor.interfaces.PersonService;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Ws_basico_consumidor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        PersonService ps;

        Person p1 = new Person();
        Person p2 = new Person();

        URL url = new URL("https://ws-basico.herokuapp.com/person?wsdl");
        QName qname = new QName("http://services.controller.ws_basico.basico.ws/","Person");
    Service ws = Service.create(url, qname);

        ps = ws.getPort(PersonService.class);

        p1.setId(0);
        p1.setName("bruno");
        p1.setAge(27);

        p2.setId(1);
        p2.setName("ana");
        p2.setAge(19);

        System.out.println("Adicionando " + p1.getName() + " status: " + ps.addPerson(p1));
        System.out.println("Adicionando " + p2.getName() + " status: " + ps.addPerson(p2));

        System.out.println(ps.getPerson(0)); // retorna o bruno.

        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(ps.getAllPersons()));

        System.out.println("Deletando " + p2.getName() + " status: " + ps.deletePerson(1));

        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(ps.getAllPersons()));

    }

}
```

Então eu tenho o seguinte erro no client:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Tipo de porta indefinido: {http://ws_basico.basico.ws/}Person
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:456)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:463)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:188)
    at ws_basico_consumidor.Ws_basico_consumidor.main(Ws_basico_consumidor.java:25)
C:\Users\bruno\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
FALHA NA CONSTRUÇÃO (tempo total: 21 segundos)
```

Considerações:

- Antes de mais nada, sei que por padrão não se usa underline em
  nomenclatura Java, mas na hora estava mais preocupado em testar e
  diferenciar dos outros projetos, apenas isso.
- Na classe "Loader" ela esta deixando a cargo do sistema em definir
  sua localização e porta, se não me engano a porta padrão do Heroku é
  a 5000.
- Este é um projeto de teste e o client também, tendo este erro
  resolvido e aprendendo os conceitos, o objetivo é que na aplicação eu
  possa acessar com um client em C#.

Desde já agradeço pela atenção.

Answer (score -1):

Acho que o problema pode ser na anotação @WebService. Definiste que a interface PersonService e a classe que a implementa PersonServiceImpl têm o mesmo nome webservice name="Person". Se fosse a ti removia isso de ambas as anotações e experimentava o seguinte:

> QName qname = new
>   QName("http://services.controller.ws_basico.basico.ws/",**"PersonServiceImpl"**);

Comment: Vou fazer este teste, mas eu basicamente fiz um ctrl+c ctrl+v do site que mencionei, pois já havia feito outros testes e nada dava certo, eu até consigo gerar o wsdl e deixar o serviço rodando, porém não consigo consumir.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o problema?

Comment: Até agora nada, eu não sei o que estou fazendo errado, pois já tentei até copiar e colar o código direto, não sei se é algum erro na hora de gerar o jar ou o que pode ser, notei que o meu wsdl é diferente do que o do tutorial, então não sei se isso é algum erro ou questão de versão apenas.

Comment: Se o WSDL está diferente aconselho a colocar igual para confirmar se não será isso

Comment: Pois é, mas eu fiz tudo conforme é dito no tutorial, a única alteração que fiz foi no arquivo Loader pois ele tem que ter as condições do heroku, mas se puder, confere ali nos links do tutorial e o do próprio WSDL que deixei ali.